# can't determine definition of operator ""/"" -- found 0 possible definitions

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


port (
  clk, rst : in std_logic;
  data_in : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  data_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
 );
```

---

```
signal div : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

How can I solve the following error on this line:

```
div <= data_in / "00001011";
```

> error  : can't determine definition of operator ""/"" -- found 0
>   possible definitions

Comment: What do you think `std_logic_vector` represent? It's just a bunch of wires. How do you do arithmetic on that? Use `unsigned` and divide by an integer. Division will require a lot of resources though... Unless it's a power-of-2

Comment: You can't (portably) mix and match Synopsys and IEEE math packages. std_logic_unsigned depends on Synopsys package std_logic_aritth for it's unsigned type declarations, operators and functions. Neither numeric_std or std_logic_unsigned provide a declaration for the "/" operator with a std_logic_vector parameter and result. Using them here is not useful. If you have the ability to use -2008 mode you could use IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned, else numeric_std with type conversions of the parameters to unsigned and the assignment right hand expression to std_logic_vector.

Comment: There are four common variants on the same error differing by tool vendor for the various VHDL operators, the error is defined by the standard. There's an in depth explanation in [no function declarations for operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861761/no-function-declarations-for-operator/50867571).

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this division (it's resource-intensive) use:

```
div <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(data_in)/unsigned'("00001011"));
```

VHDL is strongly typed and you must therefore explicitly convert between units. Some lines can end up rather long!

Comment: `data_in` being an `std_logic_vector`, the function `to_unsigned` won't compile.

Comment: @grorel Compiles just fine on my machine. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: the function prototype is `function TO_UNSIGNED (ARG, SIZE : NATURAL) return UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED;` which library do you use ?

Comment: @grorel I'm using

`library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;                                                    
use ieee.numeric_std.all; `

Comment: @grorel Gah, you're totally right. I don't know where my last comment came from. Updated the answer